# Нужна ли запятая перед "не покидая"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастный-оборот

*Получайте грузы(,) не покидая дома.*

Comment: Хороший вопрос — только непонятный. Алёна, поправьте где-нибудь (не выходя или не покидая) и дайте свое решение (или хотя бы предположение).

Comment: спасибо большое. исправила

Comment: Можно ли лицезреть вердикт? или будет редактировать еще что-то?

Comment: Алён, Римма же попросила Вас дать своё решение.

Comment: за 6 часов ни одного ответа. вы чувствуйте себя в соц сети и хотите поболтать? только болтовня, а не сайт

Comment: вам только поболтать. за 6 часов нет ни одного внятного ответа. "Напишите предложение с большой буквы" и прочий бред поступил на мой вопрос.

Comment: Алёна, не игнорируйте, пожалуйста, моих и чужих слов. Вам как автору следует хотя бы предположить, как правильно, привести какие-то свои мысли.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь не нужна запятая. Есть правило: Запятая не ставится при условии, когда деепричастный оборот (обычно со значением обстоятельства образа действия) тесно связан по содержанию со сказуемым и образует смысловой центр высказывания. Например: "Она сидела чуть откинув голову" - указывается, что она не просто сидела, а сидела с откинутой головой; "Старик шёл прихрамывая на правую ногу".